# iPhone simulator - simulate 3G connection

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator

I am testing the Reachability api, but my physical device only has WiFi access, as I don't have a phone contract.  My code needs to distinguish between being connected to 3G/2G or WiFi.  Is it possible to simulate a 3G connection on the iPhone simulator?

Clarifications: I am using Snow Leopard.  Limiting the bandwidth is not what I need.  I need for the actual interface to be identified as the 3G or 2G radio, as opposed to WiFi.

Comment: I'm not sure you can tell the difference aside from network speeds, which won't remain constant forever.

Comment: it's not a question of speed, but of identifying the interface.

Comment: You can also try the Apple developer forums if you haven't already. Another way to get a resolution is to file a bug report requesting this functionality, but I'm sure you knew that already.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you are using Lion try the [Network Link Conditioner](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/07/25/network-link-conditioner-in-lion/)

[image]

Nowdays there is a part in Preferences on the device (when registered as a developer device) where a "Network Link Conditioner" is available.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that it is a build-in-functionality in iphone-simulator. But I test it sometimes on my device with wifi (and 3g) disabled.

If you dont have an iPhone but sth. similar (Android for instance) then just enable tethering on your device and use the tethered internet-connection. Then your iPhone-Simulator only gets slow speed ;)

**edit:** another idea is to limit the bandwidth of your mac. I found [this tool](http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/index.html) online (have not tested it) which should be able to limit network-traffic (to your local router/modem)