# limit network speed for my iPad simulator

Tags: iphone

i want to test my app on the iPad simulator on all cases of the network speed 
so i want to know how to limit the network speed for my simulator

Comment: Duplicate question to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596930/iphone-simulator-simulate-3g-connection
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Network Link Conditioner, it's available on Mac OS Lion and above

See this link http://mattgemmell.com/2011/07/25/network-link-conditioner-in-lion/

Answer (score 0):

I use SpeedLimit for MAC [SpeedLimit link](http://the.taoofmac.com/space/apps/SpeedLimit)