# Simulate slow internet connection for React Native app development

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, react-native-ios

How can i simulate a slow internet connection for React Native app testing on iOs simulator?

I tried with Chrome Developers tools to change throttle in Network tab as said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313279/1206613, but with no luck.

Also tried this solution, but also no go: http://thisbythem.com/blog/simulating-a-slow-internet-connection-on-osx/

Thanks

Comment: Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596930/iphone-simulator-simulate-3g-connection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give a try with CharlesProxy, it gives you the possibility of setting the bandwidth for connection using it.

[image]

[image]